# Firebase pop() as opposite to push()?

Tags: firebase

I'd like to implement a stack (queue) that many users can push() to and many can pop() from in a FILO manner.

Is there an equivalent to `pop()` method to retrieve/remove the last item of the list?

For example:

```
var popRef = firebaseRef.pop();
```

Comment: can you rephrase the question so it will be more clear?

Comment: @salexch, of course, but which part is not clear to you?

Comment: stack-like applications

Comment: yes, you can use splice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very doable, but a tad tricky.  Since you'll have multiple users trying to remove items, you have to deal with the case of multiple users trying to remove the same item (this is really a distributed systems problem).  Presumably you only want one user to succeed.  The solution there is to use a transaction to ensure that only one user can successfully remove a particular item.

We have a "work queue" example on github that's very similar to what you're looking for: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue

The big difference between it and what you asked for is that it's FIFO instead of FILO.  To change it to be FILO, you'll want to modify this line from workqueue.js:

```
queueRef.startAt().limit(1).on("child_added", function(snap) {
```

The .startAt() there tells it to grab the first item from the *beginning* of the list (i.e. the oldest item).  To get the last item in the list (i.e. the newest item), you can change "startAt()" to "endAt()" or just omit "startAt()" entirely (by default we'll get the last item).

Answer (score 0):

You want a *"first-come-first-serve"* which is a FIFO, so you don't need `pop()` but `unshift()` which is available in JavaScript:

```
// Performs a dequeue: gets the 0-index item and removes it
// from the original array
var popRef = firebaseRef.unshift();
```

To perform FILO you have the [`pop()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp).

**FireBase update:**

```
  // Get a reference to the root of the chat data.
  var messagesRef = new Firebase('https://example37192028.firebaseio-demo.com/');
  var tokens = [];
  // When the user presses enter on the message input, write the message to firebase.
  $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          var name = $('#nameInput').val();
          var text = $('#messageInput').val();
          tokens.push(messagesRef.push({name:name, text:text}));
          $('#messageInput').val('');
      } else if (e.keyCode == 32) {
          // Removing from the stack on spacebar
          var token = tokens.pop();
          token.remove();
          $('#messageInput').val('');
      }
  });

  // Add a callback that is triggered for each chat message.
  messagesRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
      var message = snapshot.val();
      $('<div/>').text(message.text).prepend($('<em/>').text(message.name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
      $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
  });
  messagesRef.on('child_removed', function (snapshot) {
      var message = snapshot.val();
      $('<div/>').text('removed:' + message.text).prepend($('<em/>').text(message.name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
      $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
  });
```

Comment: I may have used the wrong explanation, what I meant is that first that comes gets the last data - FILO. Sorry, I'll edit the post.

Comment: And as I mentioned in other comment it is a [Firebase](http://firebase.com) related question, not the JavaScript one :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Miro firebaseRef does keep the messages in an array you can access the underlying array and perform all actions that you want.

Comment: @Miro I have implemented an example for you in the firebase demo. Check it out by pasting the code there.

Comment: Konstantin, you're not removing current LAST member of the list in the database, you're removing the one which reference you saved in your local array. What if someone else added something to the list after you? I want to be able to remove that one.